# spring jpa manyToMany composite @IdClass

Tags: java, spring, jpa, many-to-many

I have two entities `foo` and `bar` in a many to many relationship. I create a manyToMany entity FooBar for it, using their primary key's as a composite primary key Id with @IdClass:

class Foo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foos")
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "bar", orphanRemoval = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Foo_bar> fooBars;

    // constructors, getters, setters, ..
}
```

class Bar:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bars")
public class Bar implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "foo", orphanRemoval = true)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Foo_bar> fooBars;

    // constructors, getters, setters, ..
}
```

class FooBar:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(FooBarID.class)
@Table(name = "foo_bars")
public class Foo_bar implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Foo foo;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Bar bar;

    // constructors, getters, setters, ..
}
```

class FooBarId:

```
public class FooBarID implements Serializable {

    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    public FooBarID() {
    }

    public FooBarID(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((foo == null) ? 0 :     foo.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((bar == null) ? 0 :     bar.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return
                (this.foo == ((FooBarID) obj).foo)
                && (this.bar == ((FooBarID) obj).bar);

    }
}
```

If I now try to create and save a new FooBar using jpa with the code:

```
Foo foo = this.fooRepository.getByName('foo123').get();
Bar bar = this.barRepository.getByName('bar123').get();

FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
fooBar.setFoo(foo);
fooBar.setBar(bar);
this.fooBarRepository.save(fooBar); <-- exception
```

throws an `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException`: `Can not set package.Foo field package.FooBarID.foo to java.lang.String; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set package.Foo field package.FooBarID.foo to java.lang.String`

Any idea how to fix this? :/

Comment: What happens if you do 
``fooBar.setFooName(foo);
fooBar.setBarName(bar);`` instead of getName();?

Comment: It should be fairly obvious that FooBar should have  a reference to a Foo and a Bar so change as below and it will work. `fooBar.setFoo(foo); fooBar.setBar(bar);`

Comment: That's what I actually do - updated the code in my question. Error remains.

Comment: Couldn't you have posted the correct code in the first place then?

Comment: @AlanHay No, it was a mistake and Im sorry. However, I keep getting this error and have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: My first guess is that you have to set `String foo` in `FooBarID` class, as well as `String bar`, based on the error message `set package.Foo field package.FooBarID.foo to java.lang.String`.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.composite primary key ClassID's need to set the types of the primary keys instead of the classes itself (here: both String)